# Laravel, resolve dependecy by passing class name as string

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to resolve a dependecy class like this

```
app(MyClass::class);
```

it works perfectly, but what I actually need is to pass the name of the class like a string, something similar to this:

```
$className = 'MyClass';
app($className::class);
```

I tried using reflection and every possible way but without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass full namespace of your class such as:

```php
$className = "\\App\\MyClass";
app($className);
```